# What does this syntax mean in the declaration of an abstract class?

Tags: c#

I suppose that this is an easy question but I couldn't find the right answer. 
What means this syntax? I'm kind of confuse about the **new()** at the end of the line:

```
public abstract class SomeClass<E> : Controller where E : ISomeInterface, new()
{
    //code of the abstract class
}
```

Comment: it means E has to implement ISomeInterface and have an parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The new constraint specifies that any type argument in a generic class declaration must have a public parameterless constructor. To use the new constraint, the type cannot be abstract.

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx

Comment: thanks a lot! so, this means that if you don't specify the "new()" you can't instantiate the generic class?

Comment: @RGraham Yes, it applies to generic class and type E.

Answer (score 3):

You're declaring:

- an abstract class `SomeClass` that depends on type `E`;
- where `E` is `ISomeInterface` or any type that implements/derives from `ISomeInterface` and;
- has the default parameterless constructor ([`new` constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

new() means that you can instanciate class like that var e = new E();

Answer (score 1):

It's not related to being the class abstract. It's a constraint of the generic type parameter, meaning that type argument should have parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 1):

It means that `SomeClass` is a generic abstract class which inherits from the `Controller` class.
The generic type `E` is restriced to implement the interface `ISomeInterface` and must have a constructor (It should be initialized)